# How to skip a particular string during string Joining in Java?

Tags: java, string

The source code I have uploaded it will join some strings value in a one line. I want a way that I can able to skip a particular string in time of string joining. Here i have stored the strings "This","is","a","test." in a string array. I want that in time of joining a particular string will be skipped. Like I want to skip "a". How can I able to do in Java? I want a generalized way that I will able to apply for any strings.

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;
public class Test_Joiner_for_seatPlan
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            StringJoiner joinString = new StringJoiner( " ");
            String[] testStringArray = {"This","is","a","test."};

            String joinedString = null;

            for(String s : testStringArray)
              {
                joinString.add(s);
              }

            joinedString = joinString.toString();

            System.out.println("After Joining the String:\n"+joinedString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: by a conditional statement.

Comment: Some way other than `if (!s.equals("a"))` ?

Comment: provide a `List` or `Map`(would be faster) of String that should be excluded and just check if the `List` contains the value or if the key for the `Map` has any value in your loop.

Comment: Question is somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array - at least for some extra reading material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with not equal condition with string. but its not feasible as its check everytime `a` value.

```
for(String s : testStringArray)
{
  if(!s.equals("a")){
      joinString.add(s);
   }
}
```

If you have a list of values like a,b,c than you can do like this:

```
 Set<String> exclude =  new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
 for(String s : testStringArray)
    {
      if(!exclude.contains(s)){
          joinString.add(s);
       }
  }
```

Comment: You describe a repeated string comparison as "not feasible", but then repeatedly create an `Arrays.ArrayList`...

Comment: yeah its true. but explaining way of conditional checking to OP. He may not know how to write condition!! thanks

Comment: There's nothing about it which is "not feasible". Also: it's more efficient to do contains on a `Set` (e.g. a `HashSet`) since it doesn't have to iterate all elements.

Comment: @AndyTurner its true. updated answer thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
**Code:**

```
for(String s : testStringArray){ 
    if(!s.equals("a")){  // replace 'a' with the required character or word you want to ignore
       joinString.add(s);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Didn't DV, but you should just use `if (!s.equals("a")) {`, rather than having an empty branch.

Comment: @AndyTurner comments addressed;

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to provide a `Map` or a `List` in which you store the String values that should get excluded in your join. Here is an example using a `Map`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] testStringArray = {"This","is","a","test."};
    Map<String, String> excludedStrings = createExcludingMap("a");
    System.out.println("After Joining the String:\n" + join(testStringArray, excludedStrings));
}

private static String join(String[] inputData, Map<String, String> excludedStrings){
    StringJoiner joinString = new StringJoiner( " ");

    String joinedString = null;

    for(String s : inputData)
    {
        if(excludedStrings.get(s) == null) // IF this return null, the String is not part of the Strings to be excluded, hence join the string
            joinString.add(s);
    }

    joinedString = joinString.toString();

    return joinString.toString();
}


private static Map<String, String> createExcludingMap(String... values) {
    Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
    for(String s : values) { // Add each value to the map, with s as key
        output.put(s, s);
    }
    return output;
}
```

output :/

```
After Joining the String:
This is test.
```

Comment: Why use a `Map` (and `Map.get`) instead of a `Set` (and `Set.contains`)?

Comment: Note that `Map` is not a `Collection`: it is part of the collections framework, but doesn't implement the `Collection` interface.

Comment: Since bmt did already provide a solution i did not want to pick up the solution with a `Set` as well. Yeah i am going to change that wording for the collection.

Comment: I think that `Map` is not an appropriate choice for this problem - there is no key/value relationship needed, and makes the point of the code harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use Split method of string. It returns array. combine each of them to get the string.

```
for (String retval: Str.split("a")){
         System.out.println(retval);
      }
```

Comment: ur answer will just print the value, but what will happen when i want to store the value for further use..

Comment: str[] st = new string[10]; str =  Str.split("a"); . st contains strings without a. so append all using foreach loop and store in a string going through index of st.

Answer (score 0):

The [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) is a utility class that was written specifically to be used with the new Java8 [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) functionality. The documentation of [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) also refers to the [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) method. It creates the StringJoiner, and wraps it in an object suitable to pass to [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-), actually a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

As part of the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API we now also have direct support for filters, it is just a matter of employing the fluent API (fluent because we keep adding `.something(...)`) to add the [`.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

You can use it as you did in your answer, but I would suggest doing it as follows:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class App {
  public static String joinString(String [] sa,Predicate<String> filter) {
    return Stream.of(sa).filter(filter).collect(joining(" "));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] testStringArray = new String [] {"This","is","a","test."};
    System.out.println(joinString(testStringArray,(s)->!s.equals("a")));
  }
}
```

I have deliberately broken it up by defining an extra method, so you can see the type of the filter passed along, exposing the [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). This would also make your function a little more generic making it work as you stated: 'I want a generalized way that I will able to apply for any strings'.

However if the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) api is flexible enough that I do not see any need to abstract your own API for it. I suggest using it as-is:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
      Stream
        .of(new String [] {"This","is","a","test."})
        .filter((s)->!s.equals("a"))
        .collect(joining(" "))
    );
  }
}
```

I could have written most of it on a single line, but I like to break it up for readability.